# Create pie chart with single sector separated from the rest?

Tags: charts, libreoffice-calc

Is it possible to use LibreOffice (I'm currently using 3.5.4) to create a pie chart where a single sector of the chart appears removed from the rest?

If so, how to do it?

Alternatively, can someone suggest an alternate tool that will allow me to create such a chart given the data? Much preferably one that is available in the Debian Squeeze main repo, but I'm willing to consider others too. Vector graphics export would be a big plus in that case.

The end result I want is something along the lines of this:

[image: Pie chart with one separated sector]

([image source](http://nl.freepik.com/index.php?goto=41&idd=518466&url=aHR0cDovL3d3dy5vcGVuY2xpcGFydC5vcmcvZGV0YWlsL3BpZS1jaGFydC1ieS1tY29s))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a pie chart, then edit it
2. Left click on the pie - a square control point will appear in each sector

[image]

3. Left click on the desired sector - it will be selected

[image]

4. Drag the sector out

[image]